# How to display in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" id="main">
      <span id="turn">X first</span>
      <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box5"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box6"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box7"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box8"></div>
      <div class="box" id="box9"></div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="replay()">Play Again</button>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js">


  </script>

</html>
```

display a gameboard in div structure not in table form. The game is should be 3 horizontal lines and three vertical lines

Comment: you want to display position like this ? X(1,1) O(2,1)

Comment: no sir i want to display the current tile number of each player example sir Player X = tile 1 if player X choose tile 1 to play his turn

Comment: and how much tiles you have in the game ?

Comment: I have 9 tiles.

Comment: so instead of naming tiles (0,1) (0,2) you want to name them 1,2,...,9 ?

Comment: I want sir to display tile 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...., 9 in particlar move choose the Play X and O. To be honest sir I dont know what I'm supposed to do in codes

Comment: Sir @Stakvino please help again

Comment: you have another problem ?

Comment: Thank you sir , yes sir how about listing the tiles chosen sir so it will display as logs of every moves

Comment: where you want to put them ? in the same place on top left and right ?

Comment: Yes sir, thank you so much highly appreciate :)

Comment: so it will be like "PlayerX moves in tile 2,3,1..." or with another form ?

Comment: Yes sir, Player X moves in tile 1,5, 3, and so on depending on which tiles his chosen it will list all the tiles chosen of Player X and O

Comment: Sir @Stakvino thank you so much :)

Comment: Sir @Stakvino this one last time help me please?

Comment: sure Yayme what's up ?

Comment: Hello honestly I really like you haha, here again thinking stupid again haha. Remember the displaying the list of the chosen moves tile of the player actually yeah I want to be display it as list / <li> which it will be display like this

Comment: Player x
<li>tiles 1</li>
<li>tiles 5</li>
<li>tiles 3</li>

Comment: Player X
<li>tiles 1</li>
<li>tiles 2</li>
like this ?

Comment: Yes sir 
Player X <ul><li>tile 1</li><li>tile 5</li><li>tile 3</li></ul>

Comment: Sir @Stakvino Thank you so much :) I want to be your friend if you ask me Thank you again :)

Comment: No problem i wish you good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir, highly appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML file change :

```html
 <span id="turnleft">Play X</span>
 <span id="turnright">Play O</span>
```

to :

```html
<div id="turnleft">
  <span>Play X</span>
  <ul id="playerX-moves"></ul>
</div>
    
<div id="turnright">
  <span>Play O</span>
  <ul id="playerO-moves"></ul>
</div>
```

add in CSS file :

```css
ul
{
  margin-top:.2em;
  padding-left:1em;
}
```

in Javascript file change :

```js
document.getElementById("turnleft").textContent = "PLayerX moves in tile " + /[0-9]/.exec(this.id)[0];

document.getElementById("turnright").textContent = "PLayerO moves in tile " + /[0-9]/.exec(this.id)[0];
```

to :

```js
var li =document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = "tile " + /[0-9]/.exec(this.id)[0]; 
document.getElementById("playerX-moves").appendChild(li);

var li =document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = "tile " + /[0-9]/.exec(this.id)[0]; 
document.getElementById("playerO-moves").appendChild(li);
```